# Is there an error stopping the products from being shown in my mens clothing section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a clothing website I have a Products class as show below

```js
const gridContainer = document.querySelector(".grid-cont");

class Product {
  constructor(imgSrc, name, detailOne, detailTwo, category) {
    this.category = category;
    this.imgSrc = imgSrc;
    this.name = name;
    this.detailOne = detailOne;
    this.detailTwo = detailTwo;

    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.classList.add("product-cont");

    container.dataset.category = this.category;

    const imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
    imgContainer.classList.add("product-img");

    const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
    imgElement.src = this.imgSrc;
    imgContainer.appendChild(imgElement);

    const productDetails = document.createElement("div");
    productDetails.classList.add("product-details");

    const productName = document.createElement("p");
    productName.textContent = this.name;
    productName.classList.add("product-name");
    productDetails.appendChild(productName);

    const detailOne = document.createElement("p");
    detailOne.textContent = this.detailOne;
    detailOne.classList.add("details"); // Use add("details") here
    productDetails.appendChild(detailOne);

    const detailTwo = document.createElement("p");
    detailTwo.textContent = this.detailTwo;
    detailTwo.classList.add("details"); // Use add("details") here
    productDetails.appendChild(detailTwo);

    container.appendChild(imgContainer);
    container.appendChild(productDetails);
    gridContainer.appendChild(container);
  }
}
```

with these 2 products intialized

```
const Product1 = new Product(
  "https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_592,f_auto/t_product_v1/02d02f4a-f1ce-4863-832d-719d1a370d96/sportswear-essential-slim-cropped-t-shirt-qP4prh.png",
  "Nike Sportswear Essential",
  "Womens Slim Cropped T-Shirt",
  "3 colours",
  "women"
);

const Product2 = new Product(
  "https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_592,f_auto/t_product_v1/28df2743-cedd-4054-9634-50197eecbe3a/sportswear-tech-fleece-windrunner-hoodie-fbnfVT.png",
  "Nike Sportswear Essential",
  "Womens Slim Cropped T-Shirt",
  "3 colours",
  "men"
);
```

here is where I differentiate between men's and women's products

```
function showProducts(category) {
  const products = document.querySelectorAll(".product-cont");
  products.forEach((product) => {
    if (product.dataset.category === category || category === "all") {
      product.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      product.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}

document
  .querySelector(".nav a:nth-child(1)")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    showProducts("women");
  });

// Example: Show men's products when clicking the "Men" link
document
  .querySelector(".nav a:nth-child(2)")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    showProducts("men");
  });

// Example: Show all products when clicking the "All" link
document
  .querySelector(".nav a:nth-child(3)")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    showProducts("all");
  });
```

how ever when i click on the link to the mens clothing page the mens products are not shown

here is the relevent html and css

Html:

```
<div class="page">
      <div class="carousel">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="four"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="women-home hidden">
        <div class="grid-cont"></div>
        <div class="women-header">
          <h1>Women's Clothing</h1>
          <div class="sort-filters">
            <div>Hide filters</div>
            <div>Sort by</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="side-bar">
          <div class="side-links">
            <a>Tops & T-Shirts</a>
            <a>Sports Bras</a>
            <a>Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a>
            <a>Shorts</a>
            <a>Trousers & Tights</a>
            <a>Jackets</a>
            <a>Tracksuits</a>
            <a>Compression & Baselayer</a>
            <a>Jumpsuits and Rompers</a>
            <a>Skirts & Dresses</a>
            <a>Bodysuits</a>
            <a>Surf & Swimwear</a>
            <a>Socks</a>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown-cont">
            <div class="side-dropdown">Gender</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Shop by price</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Sales & Offers</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Size</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Colour</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Brand</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="men-home hidden">
        <div class="grid-cont"></div>
        <div class="men-header">
          <h1>Men's Clothing</h1>
          <div class="sort-filters">
            <div>Hide filters</div>
            <div>Sort by</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="side-bar">
          <div class="side-links">
            <a>Tops & T-Shirts</a>
            <a>Sports Bras</a>
            <a>Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a>
            <a>Shorts</a>
            <a>Trousers & Tights</a>
            <a>Jackets</a>
            <a>Tracksuits</a>
            <a>Compression & Baselayer</a>
            <a>Jumpsuits and Rompers</a>
            <a>Skirts & Dresses</a>
            <a>Bodysuits</a>
            <a>Surf & Swimwear</a>
            <a>Socks</a>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown-cont">
            <div class="side-dropdown">Gender</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Shop by price</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Sales & Offers</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Size</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Colour</div>
            <div class="side-dropdown">Brand</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.women-home h1,
.men-home h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}
.women-header,
.men-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.grid-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 252px);
  left: 250px;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 175px;
  background-color: black;
}
.product-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: calc(33% - (6 * 7px));
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.product-cont:nth-child(3n-1) {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
.product-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.product-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 370px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.product-details {
  height: calc(100% - 385px);
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.product-name {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.product-details p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.details {
  color: grey;
}
.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 100px;
  max-height: calc(
    100% - 175px
  ); /* Set max-height to limit the sidebar height */
  overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.side-bar a {
  margin: 7px 0px;
  padding: 0px 25px;
}
.side-bar a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}
.side-links {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.dropdown-cont {
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
.side-dropdown {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.side-dropdown:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I've tried many things like checking there arent any typos checking if there's any differences between the mens and womens pages checking that all the functions do what they are supposed to but i can't seem to find the root of the problem If anyone could help me that would be great

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

your code seems fine. However, both images from Product1 and Product2 seem to depict women though, even though Product2 is for `category=men`

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/unruffled-khayyam-rxkhmr?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00062v6dnahe1ie1%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00022v6dhbzzhmuu%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00032v6dg8sqq54x%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00052v6dq3sbei0u%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq828ofv00022v6dhbzzhmuu%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00012v6d2u69y9h8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00022v6dhbzzhmuu%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00012v6d2u69y9h8%2522%257D%252C%2522clq828ofv00052v6dq3sbei0u%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00042v6dqgwem9aa%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00052v6dq3sbei0u%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00042v6dqgwem9aa%2522%257D%252C%2522clq828ofv00032v6dg8sqq54x%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq828ofv00032v6dg8sqq54x%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) of your code with some buttons toggling between Product1 and Product2. Perhaps I can better understand your issue if you could provide the missing html code as reference by :

```
document
  .querySelector(".nav a:nth-child(1)")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    showProducts("women");
  });

// Example: Show men's products when clicking the "Men" link
document
  .querySelector(".nav a:nth-child(2)")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    showProducts("men");
  });

// Example: Show all products when clicking the "All" link
document
  .querySelector(".nav a:nth-child(3)")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    showProducts("all");
  });
```